# How to make alert appear after setInterval() method completes its whole operation

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I want to show an alert after `setInterval()` method did all of it's operation.

`alert()` should wait until `setInterval()` is done.  But in this code `alert()` is running first, I have to try `callback()` or `promise()` method?

```js
function  checkElement() {
  var timeout = 15000;
  
  var checkExist = setInterval(function () {
    if ($('#the-canvas').length) {
      console.log("Exists!");
      clearInterval(checkExist);
    }
    else if ((timeout -= 500) < 0) {
      console.log("time out")
      clearInterval(checkExist);
    }
  }, 500);

  alert("setInterval method finished")
}
checkElement()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: put it into the function that you call after 500ms ...

Comment: Just put it where you do `clearInterval(checkExist);`

Answer (score -2):

You'll have to put it into the function that's called after the timeout:

```js
var checkExist = setInterval(function () {
    if ($('#the-canvas').length) {
        console.log("Exists!");
        clearInterval(checkExist);
    }
    else if ((timeout -= 500) < 0) {
        console.log("time out")
        clearInterval(checkExist);
    }

    alert("setInterval method finished")
}, 500);
```